# IVsTextManager::GetActiveView(true, null, ...) returns non-focused view

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vsix, vsx, vspackage

I am playing with creating a Visual Studio text editing command. I got as far as creating a package, binding the command, placing it into the menu. But what I cannot do in a Microsoft-recommended way is figure out whether there is an active text view to which the command should be applied.

I am following steps in [the VSSDK tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd884850%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (scroll down to *Using the Menu Command to Add the Comment Adornment*). Upon selecting the command from the menu, mt command handler is called all right. however, when the following exact tutorial code is executed, the results I am getting are inconsistent.

```
IVsTextManager txtMgr = (IVsTextManager)GetService(typeof(SVsTextManager));
IVsTextView vTextView = null;
int mustHaveFocus = 1;
txtMgr.GetActiveView(mustHaveFocus, null, out vTextView);
```

Now, if there are only text views, everything works as you'd expect: the active text view is returned. But throw another view in the picture (I am using a Bitmap editor), and the view returned by `GetActiveView` appears to be the *last active text view*. I. e., if I switch tabs to bring up the bitmap view over previously active view to *fileA*, the same view for *fileA* is returned. In other words, I cannot figure out whether the text view is focused or not.

Now, this seems to be insconsistent with (however poor) [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.ivstextmanager.getactiveview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `IVsTextManager::GetActiveView()`. It has to say about the first argument to the function: *if **true**, then the current UI active view is returned.* Am I reading that correctly? The behavior that I am observing seemingly corresponds to the other case: *if **false**, then the last active view is returned, regardless of whether this view is currently UI active.*

I can figure out another way of binding commands to views, namely by hooking up view creation. What worries me here is that I am apparently unable to process the command in the Microsoft-recommended way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, sorry for the confusing documentation, but this walkthrough is not something I would recommend for your case (I'm a dev on VS editor team).

As you pointed out you can handle commands much simpler by hooking up command filter via IVsTextViewCreationListener, this is actually way more common and better way, see [Walkthrough: Using a Shortcut Key with an Editor Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885474.aspx) (that is also sort of confusing title :( )

Comment: Thanks, that was what I ended up doing.

Comment: Oleg, if you are still with the same team, could you please comment on this new answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49584892/1149924 It would be great if this was documented, even if this behavior was introduced unintentionally.

Comment: Microsoft's new open source documentation is super great, and I did submit a few corrections to it already, but I had MSBuild sources and studied them, and was quite confident the corrections are valid. Here it would be better if someone inside with access to and understanding of source would do that. I could, but I just do not feel it would not be the right thing adding information obtained by probing the API as a black box. :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer from the dev on VS editor team to use a different method may work for the person who asked the original question, but for us who want to use GetActiveView for other reasons, the question remains: how does one get only text windows with focus rather than the last text window that had focus? The unreliable documentation (which suggests mustHaveFocus is a boolean even though it's an int) seems to be misleading, since setting the value to either 0 or 1 (or -1) appears to result in the last text window with focus being returned.

Comment: string GetSelection()
        {
            EnvDTE.DTE app = (EnvDTE.DTE)GetService(typeof(SDTE));
            if ((app.ActiveDocument != null) && (app.ActiveDocument.Type == "Text"))
            {
                EnvDTE.TextDocument textDoc = (EnvDTE.TextDocument)app.ActiveDocument.Object(String.Empty);
                if (!textDoc.Selection.IsEmpty)
                {
                    return textDoc.Selection.Text;
                }
                else
                    return "Empty selection";
            }
            return "Not a text document";
        }

Comment: You can ignore the previous comment. I was trying to show an alternate approach using the DTE calls. It still didn't seem to know which window was the active window, and crashed with an Invalid Argument exception when the VS Property window was active and (app.ActiveDocument != null)  executed.

Answer (score 1):

`GetActiveView(fMustHaveFocus, pBuffer, out ppView)` apparently ignores `fMustHaveFocus` if `pBuffer` is `null`.  If it is not `null`, it works as documented.

So you can get the active-and-must-have-focus view by calling `GetActiveView` a second time with the buffer of the view that it returned the first time.

```
IVsTextView vsTextView;
IVsTextLines vsTextLines;
// `GetActiveView` apparently ignores `fMustHaveFocus` if `pBuffer` is null, so call
// it a second time with the buffer from the view it returned the first time to find
// out if the view actually has focus.
if (textManager.GetActiveView(1, null, out vsTextView) == VSConstants.S_OK &&
    vsTextView.GetBuffer(out vsTextLines) == VSConstants.S_OK &&
    textManager.GetActiveView(1, vsTextLines, out vsTextView) == VSConstants.S_OK)
{
    // vsTextView has focus.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, an interesting solution. Since a lot of time passed and many VS versions out there, could you please add to the answer what VS version(s) did you test your solution with? Since this is the documentation gray area, that would be very helpful! Certainly not vs2012 from my original question :)

Comment: I'll update tags when you add this info, so other people can find your answer.

Comment: I tested against VS 2017, but I have no reason to believe that it wouldn't work for earlier versions, considering that the documentation for `fMustHaveFocus` hasn't changed in the interim, and since it still has this undocumented behavior, probably the implementation hasn't either.